# How do I sustain filter results when leaving tab and returning?

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm filtering a gallery of thumbnails of .PDFs.

When I filter results, open a .pdf, close it I need the screen to return to the filter results.

The .pdfs are set to open in same tab.

The function is using hide and show to filter:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".filter-button").click(function () {
                var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                if (value == "all") {
                    $('.filter').show('1000');
                }
                else {
                    $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
                    $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
                    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                }
            });
            if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    </script>


 <script>
        // Check if the sessionStorage object exists
        if (sessionStorage) {
            // Store data
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", "activeFilter");
            // Retrieve data
              localStorage.getItem("filTerm") 
        } 
    </script>
```

I'm attempting to initiate the session storage. I have some of the concepts down but am very unskilled at JavaScript.

What I think I need is to grab the current filter string (from the filter function), put it in storage and then assign the string to .attr('data-filter'). That last line should be putting the stored value (the current filter term) back into the filter function. How do I do that?

sessionStorage.data-filter = "filTerm" ?

Update 9/25: I have not achieved saving the filter. JS in this fiddle is filtering, the search function is barely limping, the scripts conflict.

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ewebster/a81v1q46/27/

I have not been able to implement Pie Bies script in his answer below, which looks like it has the mechanism to store my filters and implement them upon page reload. I think I just didn't get the variable names to agree. I am very new at JavaScript and Programming. Any help getting this code to work is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use 'sessionStorage' or 'localStorage' to store what filters are active before the user leaves the page. When the user comes back to the page, check if sessionStorage or localStorage have relevant saved 'filter' options, and reapply them if necessary.

Comment: you could always maintain the current tab and open the pdfs with the target attribute set to = "_blank". If you really want to store data then this may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Targeting new tab is not an option. How would I go about saving the state to local or session storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to separate your model, controller and view. This sounds complex, but it's actually not that hard. In your case, all you need to do is put everything that manipulates your UI in a different function from your interaction. This makes code easier to read, and to maintain (say if you want to add more feedback).

I've added comments in the following code to explain what's what. If something's not clear, leave a comment and I'll try to explain better.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //declare a global variable
  var filterVal;
  //check if sessionStorage exists and if so, if there is a var called fillTerm
  //if not, set it to a default value (all)
  if ( sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm") ){
    filterVal = sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm");
  }  else {
    filterVal = "all";
    sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
  }

  //now let's attach some interaction to our buttons
  $(".filter-btn").on("click", function () {
    //get the value for our filter
    filterVal = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    //store it in the session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
    //call our view update function
    updateView();
  });

  //this is the function that manipulates the UI
  function updateView(){
    //default situation: all is visible
    if( !filterVal || filterVal === "all" ){
      $('.filter').show('1000');
    } 
    //hide all and show filtered values
    else {
      $(".filter").hide('3000');
      $('.filter').filter('.' + filterVal).show('3000');
    }
  };

  //update the view when the page loads
  updateView();

});
```

I've also created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akphaLnp/4/) to illustrate the code. Might be that your browser blocks the links because they are run in a sandbox. If you unblock those, it should work.

Comment: Thanks PieBie, this works perfectly (after I change 1 variable name). Thanks for teaching and showing.

Comment: More than welcome. For future visitors, here's the chat resulting from this Q&A containing more info: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66020/room-for-webster-and-piebie

Comment: And here is a fiddle showing working code: https://jsfiddle.net/ewebster/a81v1q46/28/  It's hard to see the filtering and saving the filters on return, but it does.

Comment: The animation occurs on return to the tab, is there a way to stop that?